# Changing Wamp Server MySQL and mariadb port and Projects link for index.php

Tags: wamp

1. Changing Wamp Server MySQL and MariaDB port ?
   Wamp Server version: 3.2.0
   mariadb port=3306
   mysql port=3308

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXi9c.png)

wamp server icon right mouse click->Tools->(MariaDb) Use a port other than->3307 ok

wamp server icon right mouse click->Tools->(Mysql) Use a port other than->3306 ok

restart wamp server...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oStRX.png)

2. Projects link for index.php ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZooR.png)

index.php line:346

```
    $projectContents .= '<li>'.$file.'</li>';
```

convert

```
    $projectContents .= '<li> <a href="'.$file.'" >'.$file.'</a></li>';
```

Update Wamp Server version: 3.3.0

index.php line:547

```
... : '<li>'.$file.'</li>';
```

convert

```
... : '<li><a href="'.$file.'" >'.$file.'</a></li>';
```

Comment: Make a Virtual Host for each site. See [The need for Virtual Hosts](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757) and [Create a Virtual Host the easy Way](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,146746)

Comment: Many users with the Mysql port set to 3308 by default in Wamp Server 3.2.0 installation do not know how to change this. I solved this problem. If the topic comes to the top, it becomes a useful sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a solution that just requires right-clicking on the WAMP icon, go to "Tools" and click on "**Invert default DBMS MariaDB <-> MySQL**", that should work. It will set MySQL as a default engine, change the port numbers for you and restart the services all by itself.

It is more efficient than the one you provided because the port number 3306 in WAMP Server is now reserved for the default MariaDB in all newer installations starting from v3.2.0. Therefore, you can no longer change the port number by selecting "**Use a port other than xxxx**" and you will get an error message. Even re-writing the **.ini** files doesn't get the job done, save the procedure I explained above.